# How to reset Kobo web browser bookmarks on Kobo Mini

Tags: ebook-readers, kobo

I have made many bookmarks on my Kobo, but I don't want any of them anymore. How can I clear the bookmarks in the Kobo web browser?

Answer (score 2):

there should be an "x" ico next to each bookmark URL, and when pressed, a box should pop up and ask you if you would like to delete the bookmark. Simply press yes if you do and no to exit.